# Microsoft OpenId login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openid, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm having serious problems with an app which must integrate with Microsofts Open Id provider.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 with the Microsoft.Owin libraries. My Startup.Auth file looks like this:

```
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msClientId"],
    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msClientSecret"]
});
```

So I do the following Make request to my external login MVC Action.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string connectionId)
{
    return new   ChallengeResult(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(provider), Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/Login/ExternalLoginCallback?connectionId=" + connectionId);
}
```

My Class Challenge Result looks like this:

```
private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
    public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
            : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
    {
    }

    public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
    {
        LoginProvider = provider;
        RedirectUri = redirectUri;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
        if (UserId != null)
        {
            properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
        }
        context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
    }
}
```

I unfortunately immediately I am redirected to the Microsoft account login I just get:

The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf' or a URL which matches the redirect URI registered for this client application.&state=9Y9inDc4SVQTd_I4ZoLwuLPTZa5i-4NapEWzuspU9B_jz1t4aXfPY239FXx2xyI-v9xW-0fgU0kwsZVzYXOtiPhoGH9_h4aiS2Q7FlJGFNviREMLRNnfHfeYoG0m0wSgO7ZZcsJztIcgPEPdo70HkN4mCynng6bx7-nR6i7WN7DQ0SYRXrxmb2hhHDvxTWeTQAfpxKWAezJzDqdEfhoDx1VyRGC-5pCxVbhB5VF2Sb9x5TL0KWb4tXgjYSHbejDlzwMQfgcVf0SB0qRRIi2YNCEbWi6_KbGADRCN-DZ7rpVd_n695nRNQXwhQvYHTqAJr3L1dny3NvbCmYJ9SRIt6w

As the actual URL. The page just says a technical problem occurred. I am at a bit of a loss.

I've checked that the request sent out to the actual MS Provider and it looks like this:
(Note substitutions for the obvious security concerns)

But I've checked that the client Id is right and the redirect_uri parameter matches the one I set in the MS account setup.

/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=&scope=wl.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=&state=zFGr4tzGDqMUpH7yVp0dB8JNoM_D6SFSiLa3NoKhF15O5mAkW7N51wB9vjzs1_PR7WQewUWYjLxfHY865EwN3EuEVIHp_S4m_q32s9DPG_dNsZ_wdEsOUe7FE3VY16jPS6WWeI-VnMu12RXvIqVnvH9tVXVc8QLUe8s1sZc5HFYWCtqiyejmw-MKO4MV1_DRoisn2lAO6rRhvyT-LvZBzZ20-CiFkxmVhq8DzdCnFn3Ya7sWyNzTzu1d1u_q71VBY_ot5sqUx-YEvLqcaNwDOHmFUVTpe5ynVKc8203pxqwlpNbfy8hrqxBuJWAGhiHuOIAMo5HuRv8kJJgmGOz4OQ

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this in development environment? what is the URL you use for your app, have you setup one in host file and using local IIS?

Comment: Hi, Yes have tried both dev environment and local environment. We have a rule on the network which redirects a specific url. localhost.xxx.com to 127.0.0.1. I've tried a live URL and neither seem to work. Both fail with the same problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, local URL should be something like somthing.something.com. If you use it correctly, then try using directly UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication without creating new object of that.

```
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
                clientId: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msClientId"],
                clientSecret: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msClientSecret"]);
```

Further you need to correctly setup redirect url on your app which should ending /signin-microsoft.

Follow [this](http://www.beabigrockstar.com/guides/aspnet-oauth/aspnet-mvc-microsoft-login) article properly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case because I used Azure Active Directory OpenID and I have to remove this line

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

Hope this helps
Best regards